# Center UIPageControl after orientation change

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to centralize a `UIPageControl` in portrait and landscape modes, but it isn't working, the x changes after device rotation.

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init] ;  
    [self renderMyView];
    [self.view addSubview:pageControl];
}

- (void)renderMyView
{
   if(isPortrait)
   {
        pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(200, 976, 0, 0);
   } else {
        pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(200, 720, 0, 0);
   }
}
```

The `renderMyView` is executed on `didLoad` and `didRotate`.

At first time `viewDidLoad` works well in portrait and landscape, but if I rotate the device the `pageControl` appears in a different x `!= 200`.

I've also tried `pageControl.center`, but it didn't work.

How can I keep it centralized?

Answer (score 5):

1) In `viewDidLoad` call `renderMyView`.

2) After device has rotated **don't** call method `renderMyView`

3) Replace your `renderMyView` with this one:

```
- (void)renderMyView
{
    if(isPortrait)
    {
         pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(200, 976, 0, 0);
    } else {
         pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(200, 720, 0, 0);
    }
    pageControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
}
```

So, don't call my `renderMyView` more then one time. `AutoresizingMask` will do all you need.

Tell me, please, if it works for you.

PS: For more information about the `autoresizingMask`, read the [UIView Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

Answer (score 1):

probably a very old question, but I'll share my way to center the UIPageControl. Just set the width of the UIPageControl to be the same width as the view's bounds size width. So, In portrait mode it will be 768 and in the landscape it will be 1024. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIView autoresizingMask in code:

```
pageControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Or you can also do this in interface builder.